# Can't connect to localhost database from node.js server

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

Been having a lot of trouble trying to connect to to my localhost database. I've tried using the [mysql](https://npmjs.org/package/mysql) and [mysql-simple](https://npmjs.org/package/mysql-simple) node modules but in both cases I just can't get it to connect.

Here's what I used with the 'mysql' module:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  port     : '8000',
  user     : 'uber',
  password : 'pass',
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;

      console.log('Connection Successful');
});


connection.query('USE someDB', function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('Query Successful');
});
```

And here' what I used with the 'mysql-simple' module:

```
var database = require('mysql-simple');
database.init('uber', 'pass', 'mysql', 'localhost', 8000);

database.querySingle('SELECT Host FROM user', function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error fetching some active users: ' + err);
        return;
    }
    log('Query Successful');
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
        console.log('got active user ' + results[i]);
}
```

In both cases, when I run my node.js server, it never logs that its connected. I've tried replacing localhost with '127.0.01' and creating a new user to make sure the password is correct, but to no avail. Why isn't it connecting?

Thanks

Comment: can you do this from the commandline: `mysql -ppass -u uber -h localhost someDB` ?

Comment: check the below thread to solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947577/cannot-connect-to-mysql-database-on-node-js

Comment: @Nikolai i have the same problem. npm package: `mysql2`. OS is: ´debian 10´ i can access to mysql in command line with this command: `mysql -u root --password=´your password´`. can you fix it?

Answer (score 7):

It's most likely that networking is turned off, that means that mysql server communicates with clients via UNIX sockets and not via TCP/IP. You can check that out running mysql client and run "status" command. If you see port number there, then your mysql server communicates via TCP/IP, or else you'll see something like "socket pathname…", get the pathname and give it to node.js connection parameters, e.g.

...
socketPath: '/opt/lampp/var/...',
...

Check that out in https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql page (search for "socketPathname")

Hope, that's your problem.

Comment: I used `socketPath : 'my/path/to/socket'` to great effect. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

You should use mysql_config to show the path to socket.

This a sample on my MAC

```
QuyLes-MacBook-Pro:freelancer quyle$ mysql_config
Usage: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config [OPTIONS]
Options:
        --cflags         [-I/Applications/MAMP/Library/include -fno-omit-frame-pointer   -g -DNDEBUG]
        --include        [-I/Applications/MAMP/Library/include]
        --libs           [-L/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib  -lmysqlclient  -lz]
        --libs_r         [-L/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib   -lmysqlclient_r  -lz]
        --plugindir      [/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/plugin]
        --socket         [/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock]
        --port           [0]
        --version        [5.5.42]
        --libmysqld-libs [-L/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib  -lmysqld]
        --variable=VAR   VAR is one of:
                pkgincludedir [/Applications/MAMP/Library/include]
                pkglibdir     [/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib]
                plugindir     [/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/plugin]
```

and then, you add key socketPath for yourMysqlConnection.
bellow on my sample

```
MysqlServer: {
     adapter: 'sails-mysql',
     host: 'localhost',
     user: 'root', //optional
     password: 'root', //optional
     database: 'nodejs', //optional,
     socketPath: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'    
},
```

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
database.init('uber', 'pass', 'mysql', 'localhost', 8000);
```

to

```
database.init('uber', 'pass', 'mysql', 'localhost', 3306);
```

and you should be through

Comment: It now gives me this error: 'Error: connect ECONNREFUSED'

Also why port 3306?

Comment: mysql is running on 3306 port by default , check for UNAME / PASSWORD and see if it is started

Comment: check UNAME & PASSWORD and they are correct, still gives me the same error - made new user to be sure

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that MySQL and express are running on the same port. 
I had MySQL bundled from XAMPP, that ran on Port 3036. 
On setting app.listen to 3036, my code worked. FINALLY!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it's work for me

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection(
    {
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'root',
      password : '',
      database : 'urdatabase',
    }
);

connection.connect();


query = connection.query("SELECT * FROM UrTable;");
    query
    .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log( err );

    })
    .on('result', function( data ) {
        socket.emit('YourData',data);
    });
```

I hope this will be helpful for you

Comment: Still no luck I'm afraid :(
when i run it I just get
    { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      syscall: 'connect',
      fatal: true }

Comment: Did you run your MySQL server (Wamp or Xampp ...) ?? if yes try to comment **skip-networking** in **mysql.conf.**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, anything happened, so I solved by generating new GRANTs with a new user for nodejs apps

Answer (score 0):

Its due to the networking is turned off in MySQL configurations.

In Ubuntu 20.04.2 and MySQL 8.x.x(its worked in my case) you can find this settings in

> /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/override.conf

there will be a **ExecStart** key and its have multiple configurations.
Here you can provide **--skip-networking** as **OFF**

```
--skip-networking=OFF
```

And you have to restart your service

```
systemctl restart mysql.service
```

It will allow you to connect localhost

Comment: It doesn't work for me as there is no directory mysql.service.d/override.conf within the folder at /etc/systemd/system. I'm also on Ubuntu 20.04.2 and MySQL 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 ... I wonder if there may be a clash between Ubuntu 20.04.2 and MySQL 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1  ...