# It's possible to make a connection using Node.js and relational data bases, like, MySQL or MS SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, json, node.js, web-services

I'm in a project where I would like to use Node.js as a backend lenguage, maybe, create a Node.js Web Service to return JSON data, but, this project is using MySQL data base, It's possible to connect Node.js with MySQL?...How?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't connect to localhost database from node.js server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493224/cant-connect-to-localhost-database-from-node-js-server)

Comment: the easiest way (even easier than asking here) is to google 'nodejs mysql' and get all sorts of libraries and tutorials on that

Answer (score 0):

There's an NPM module for MySQL. Installation and usage instructions can be found on the [NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql).